# git handle untracked binary files

Tags: git, binary, bundle

I am using `git` for my thesis. The project contains text files (code, `*.tex`) and binary files (figures).

- text files are tracked by the git repository
- binary files are not tracked by git, but reside in the same directory.

I am working on my desktop and on a laptop, sometimes synced via ssh, sometimes via an USB drive. My problem is how to handle this syncing properly. If I had only code I would use `git pull`, `git push` or `git bundle`. The problem is that this will not include the binary files (i.e., a figure I made on my desktop will not be transfered to the laptop, so `latex` on the laptop fails because a figure is missing). Therefore I currently use `rsync` for synchonizing, but then I loose many advantages of using `git`.

What I would like to do:

- tell `git` "here are some binary files, please include them when doing a `git push` or `git pull` or `git bundle`
- since this are binary files I do NOT want them to be tracked, i.e., I only want the current state to be copied, NOT the changes

So far I could only come up with workaround solutions (building a shell script around `git` for code and `rsync` for syncing the binary files). But this makes working awkward, so I am looking for a more optimal solution.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to track the binary files? Are they overly large and changing frequently? If they're not both of these, then I'd just add them to the repo and track them.

Comment: They will not change often, but they do (new version of a plot with updated data, changing details in a figure). Even if there are only a few revisions the size of the repository would explode quickly.

Comment: Have you tried tracking them and seen a considerable performance hit? Even if you had a hundred figures, any image format you're handling in TeX wouldn't generate a .git directory larger than many applications. If you don't like the latency off the USB drive, have you considered github or bitbucket? The former is $7 a month for your needs. The latter is free.

Answer (score 2):

I think git-annex does exactly what you need:
http://git-annex.branchable.com/

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to keep the binary files on a separate branch (possibly orphaned using `git checkout --orphan <branchname>`?) and only ever use `git commit --amend`.  Pushes and pulls involving that branch would pretty much always have to use `--force`, but it could work.

Although this would leave some bloat in the repository, there would be an upper limit because of garbage collection, since it wouldn't be keeping the history of the binary files.

Comment: I fail to see how this would work. When I switch from the orphaned binary-branch back to one of my source-branches, the files I added while working in the binary-branch are no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably organize things this way:

```
project
   .git
   .tex files
   code files
   data symlink to ../project-data
project-data
   images, etc
```

That way you can use `rsync` freely on the project-data directory without having to be overly concerned with exclude patterns and/or damaging your repository, and use `git fetch` and git `push` freely in the main project without having to worry about the noise of untracked files. Of course your code and .tex files will need to be modified slightly to pull things from a subdirectory instead of where they're at now.

Comment: I agree that this solution works perfectly well, however it is still a workaround: I always have to do two things: `git fetch` and `rsync`.